# persisting a json to mongodb how to specify a date attribute

Tags: json, mongodb, date

I am persisting a JSON object to MongoDB here is relevant snippet:

```
Viewed: [
-{
ViewedID: "8992ade400a"
Dockey: "3323aba3233"
PID: "32399a"
actionsTaken: "email|direct message|report seeker"
viewDate: "01-APR-2014"
MessageSent: "true"
-Message: [
-{
MessageID: "123aca323"
Delivered: "True"
Opened: "True"
ClickThroughRate: "NotBad"
MessageDate: "02-APR-2014"
-Response: [
-{
ResponseId: "a323a9da"
ResponseDate: "23-APR-2014"
}
]
}
```

Here is how I am setting the JSON on my persisting object:

```
 trackingData.setEventdata((DBObject)JSON.parse(tracker.getEventData().toString()));
```

where `tracker.getEventData()` returns `ObjectNode` when I persist the DBObject to mongo I see the dates such `"viewDate" : "01-APR-2014"` and `"ResponseDate" : "23-APR-2014"` as Strings.

I need these attributes to be converted to type date so I may query against these dates. Is there anyway to specify that these be handled as date objects either before or after parsing that JSON to DBObject?

Cheers,

Will

Answer (score 0):

The `com.mongodb.util.JSON.parse` method supports [Extended JSON format](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/), so if the JSON was actually formatted that way then this would automatically be cast as a date.

But since it isn't then you would either need to implement a custom parser that handles the "date" elements in your JSON or otherwise just manipulate the BSON before sending it on to MongoDB.

The simplest way is just to manipulate, with something like as shown in this example:

```
    try {
        DBObject content = (DBObject)com.mongodb.util.JSON.parse("{ \"date\": \"01-APR-2014\" }");
        System.out.println(content);

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        content.put("date",sdf.parse((String) content.get("date")));

        System.out.println(content);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

So after processing the `.parse()` you can basically do that date conversion for each relevant date field in your source. Also keep in mind that the data is going to be stored with dates as "UTC/GMT", so make sure that the Timezone you are getting from the source is correctly represented.